# Zend Framework non-existent controller redirects to home page?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, frameworks, controller

When I type an invalid url (non-existent controller), it displays the homepage rather than return a 404 Page Not Found page. Does anyone know the possible reason?

Thanks

Comment: Does it hit the error controller first?

Comment: What you are using CMS for zend?

Answer (score 0):

Have checked if there is any plugins are registered in the bootstrap and if is it configured to catch the exceptions or set any ACL mechanisms.
Also check the error controller too. may be there is some forwarding methods implemented there.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i've had the same problem and i now know how to fix it:

within the bootstrap have the following init

```
function _initModules()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('frontController') ;
        $front = $this->getResource('frontController') ;
        $front->addModuleDirectory(APPLICATION_PATH . "/modules");
        $front->setParam("useDefaultControllerAlways", false);
    }
```

Setting 'useDefault....' will use the default controller when a 404 occurs.

You should also make sure your error controller is setup correctly